# Joining Rooms with Socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I am trying to create a kind of room system for a messaging system I'm making with socket.io for a react project and it doesn't seem to connecting correctly.

This is rather complicated so Ill walk you through a use case.

1. User logins and its greeted with this page:

[image]

As you can see my user is logged in at the bottom left

2. This user now wants to send a message to someone
   Lets use test seeing as test is the current profile in view
3. The user clicks the message button in the top right of the profile view
   This takes them to this screen:

[image]

They can now message them whatever message they would like to send

This is now where the issue lies. Obviously test will want to see what admin has sent them this is where I want a room system. So that when the logged in user clicks on the user to message it creates a room where those two users can message between each other. I've tried to achieve this with socket.io as my previous GET and POST request version wasn't in real-time. So far you can only send messages there is no kind of back and forth between users.

Through my testing ive made a room ID and logged it to the console with the following:

```
joined room: admin admin_test test
{
  sender: 'admin admin',
  recipient: 'test test',
  message: 'a',
  time: '17:47',
  room: 'admin admin_test test'
}
joined room: admin admin_test test
{
  sender: 'test test',
  recipient: 'admin admin',
  message: 'a',
  time: '17:47',
  room: 'admin admin_test test'
}
```

This does indicate that the messages are being sent and they are under the same room ID. Im unsure as to why they then don't receive messages. I would like any solutions so that these two can send messages back and forth between each other.

Heres the backend where the socket is managed:

```
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const socket = (server) => {
  const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
  });

  //On connection
  io.on('connection', socket => {    
    //On join room
    socket.on('join', room => {
       socket.join(room);

        console.log('joined room: ' + room);
    });

    //On message send
    socket.on('send_message', (data) => {
      //Log message
      console.log(data);

      //Emit to recipient
      io.to(data.room).emit('receive_message', data);
    });
  });
};

module.exports = socket;
```

The client that handles messaging:

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import { ArrowLongUpIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';

export default function Message({sender, recipient, profilePicture, roomId}) {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:8080');

    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

    const bottomRef = useRef(null);
    
    //Sends message to server
    const sendMessage = async () => {
        //If input isnt empty
        if (message !== '') {
            //Formats message
            const messageData = {
                sender: sender,
                recipient: recipient,
                message: message,
                time: new Date().getHours() + ':' + new Date().getMinutes(),
                room: roomId
            };

            //Sends to back end
            await socket.emit('send_message', messageData);
            //Shows previously sent message
            setMessages((list) => [...list, messageData]);    
            
            //Clears input
            setMessage('');
        };
    };

    useEffect(() => {           
        //Receive message from back-end
        socket.on('receive_message', (data) => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(roomId);
            //If message is for this room
            if (data.room === roomId) {
                console.log(data);
                //Show message
                setMessages((list) => [...list, data]);
            }
        });
    }, [roomId]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Scroll to bottom every time messages change
        bottomRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      }, [messages]);

    return (
        /* Messages */
        <div class="flex flex-col h-full max-h-[750px] w-full px-4 py-6">
            {/* Message list */}
            <div class="h-full overflow-y-scroll pb-4">
                <p class="text-center italic text-gray-400">Chat started with: <span class="font-semibold">{recipient}</span></p>
                <div class="grid grid-cols-12">
                    {/* Individual message */}
                    {messages.map((messageContent, index) => {
                        return (
                            messageContent.sender === sender ? (
                                /* Sender */
                                <div key={index} class="col-start-6 col-end-13 p-2 rounded-lg">
                                    <div class="flex justify-start flex-row-reverse">        
                                        {/* Message content */}
                                        <div class="flex flex-col space-y-1.5">
                                            <div class="relative mr-3 text-sm bg-blue-100 py-2 px-4 shadow rounded-xl">
                                                <p ref={bottomRef}>{messageContent.message}</p>
                                            </div>

                                            <p class="text-xs text-gray-400 italic text-right mr-4">{messageContent.time}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            ) : (
                                
                                /* Recipient */
                                <div key={index} class="col-start-1 col-end-8 p-3 rounded-lg">
                                    <div class="flex flex-row">
                                        <div class="flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 flex-shrink-0">
                                            <img
                                                src={'http://localhost:8080/public/' + profilePicture}
                                                alt="Profile picture"
                                                class="rounded-full"
                                            ></img>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="flex flex-col space-y-2">
                                            <div class="relative ml-3 text-sm bg-white py-2 px-4 shadow rounded-xl">
                                                <p ref={bottomRef}>{messageContent.message}</p>
                                            </div>

                                            <p class="text-xs text-gray-400 italic text-right ml-4">{messageContent.time}</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            )
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* Input */}
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center pt-3">
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Enter your message"
                    value={message}
                    onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
                    onKeyPress={(e) => {
                        e.key === 'Enter' && sendMessage();
                    }}
                    class="w-full h-10 px-4 text-sm  rounded-3xl focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300 focus:ring focus:ring-opacity-40 focus:ring-blue-200">
                </input>

                <div class="ml-6">
                    <button 
                        onClick={sendMessage}
                        class="flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 text-blue-600"
                    >
                        <svg class="w-5 h-5 transform rotate-90 -mr-px"
                            fill="none"
                            stroke="currentColor"
                            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round"
                                stroke-linejoin="round"
                                stroke-width="2"
                                d="M12 19l9 2-9-18-9 18 9-2zm0 0v-8"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* Back to top button */}
            <div class="flex justify-center my-5">
                <button
                    onClick={() => {document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;}}
                    class="inline-flex items-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-600 focus:ring-offset-2"
                >
                    Back to top

                    <ArrowLongUpIcon class="h-4 w-4" aria-hidden="true" />
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

And Message's parent component that handles its opening and closing, please not this file is very large so ive removed anything that wasnt relevant but some clutter still remains:

```
    const socket = io('http://localhost:8080');

    const roomId = [sender, profileFirstName + " " +  profileLastName].sort().join('_');

    const messageHandler = () => {
        socket.emit('join', roomId);

        setRenderMessage(!renderMessage);
    };

    return (
        <div class="flex">
            <SideBar />

            <div className="flex w-screen h-auto">
                <div className="flex min-w-0 flex-1 flex-col overflow-hidden">
                    <div className="relative z-0 flex flex-1 overflow-hidden">
                        <main className="relative z-0 flex-1 overflow-y-auto focus:outline-none xl:order-last">
                            {/* Breadcrumb */}
                            <article>
                                {/* Profile header */}
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <img
                                            className="h-32 w-full object-cover lg:h-48"
                                            src={profile.coverImageUrl}
                                            alt=""
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="mx-auto max-w-5xl px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                                        <div className="-mt-12 sm:-mt-16 sm:flex sm:items-end sm:space-x-5">
                                            <div className="flex">
                                                <img
                                                    className="h-24 w-24 rounded-full ring-4 ring-white sm:h-32 sm:w-32"
                                                    src={
                                                        "http://localhost:8080/public/" +
                                                        profile.profile_picture
                                                    }
                                                    alt=""
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="mt-6 sm:flex sm:min-w-0 sm:flex-1 sm:items-center sm:justify-end sm:space-x-6 sm:pb-1">
                                                <div className="mt-6 min-w-0 flex-1 sm:hidden 2xl:block">
                                                    <h1 className="truncate text-2xl font-bold text-gray-900">
                                                        {profile.name}
                                                    </h1>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="justify-stretch mt-6 flex flex-col space-y-3 sm:flex-row sm:space-y-0 sm:space-x-4">
                                                    <button
                                                        type="button"
                                                        onClick={messageHandler}
                                                        className="inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-600 focus:ring-offset-2"
                                                    >
                                                        <EnvelopeIcon
                                                            className="-ml-1 mr-2 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400"
                                                            aria-hidden="true"
                                                        />
                                                        {renderMessage ? (
                                                            <span>
                                                                Close Message
                                                            </span>
                                                        ) : (
                                                            <span>Message</span>
                                                        )}
                                                    </button>

                                                    {/* <button
                                                        type="button"
                                                        className="inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-600 focus:ring-offset-2"
                                                    >
                                                        <PhoneIcon className="-ml-1 mr-2 h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
                                                        <span>Call</span>
                                                    </button> */}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="mt-6 hidden min-w-0 flex-1 sm:block 2xl:hidden">
                                            <h1 className="truncate text-2xl font-bold text-gray-900">
                                                {profile.name}
                                            </h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                            

                                {/* If state is true render Messaging component */}
                                {renderMessage ? (
                                    <Message
                                        sender={sender}
                                        recipient={profileFirstName + " " +  profileLastName}
                                        profilePicture={profileProfilePicture}
                                        roomId={roomId}
                                    />
                                ) : (
                                    <>
                                        {/* Description list */}
                                        <div className="mx-auto mt-6 max-w-5xl px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                                            <dl className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-4 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-2">
                                                {Object.keys(
                                                    profile.fields
                                                ).map((field) => (
                                                    <div
                                                        key={field}
                                                        className="sm:col-span-1"
                                                    >
                                                        <dt className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">
                                                            {field}
                                                        </dt>
                                                        <dd className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-900">
                                                            {
                                                                profile.fields[
                                                                    field
                                                                ]
                                                            }
                                                        </dd>
                                                    </div>
                                                ))}
                                                <div className="sm:col-span-2">
                                                    <dt className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">
                                                        About
                                                    </dt>
                                                    <dd
                                                        className="mt-1 max-w-prose space-y-5 text-sm text-gray-900"
                                                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                                            __html: profile.about_me,
                                                        }}
                                                    />
                                                </div>
                                            </dl>
                                        </div>

                                        {/* Team member list */}
                                        <div className="mx-auto mt-8 max-w-5xl px-4 pb-12 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                                            <h2 className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-500">
                                                Previously worked with
                                            </h2>
                                            <div className="mt-1 grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 sm:grid-cols-2">
                                                {teamPlaceHolder.map(
                                                    (person) => (
                                                        <div
                                                            key={person.handle}
                                                            className="relative flex items-center space-x-3 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 bg-white px-6 py-5 shadow-sm focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-blue-600 focus-within:ring-offset-2 hover:border-gray-400"
                                                        >
                                                            <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                                                                <img
                                                                    className="h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
                                                                    src={
                                                                        person.imageUrl
                                                                    }
                                                                    alt=""
                                                                />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div className="min-w-0 flex-1">
                                                                <a
                                                                    href="#"
                                                                    className="focus:outline-none"
                                                                >
                                                                    <span
                                                                        className="absolute inset-0"
                                                                        aria-hidden="true"
                                                                    />
                                                                    <p className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                                                                        {
                                                                            person.name
                                                                        }
                                                                    </p>
                                                                    <p className="truncate text-sm text-gray-500">
                                                                        {
                                                                            person.role
                                                                        }
                                                                    </p>
                                                                </a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    )
                                                )}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </>
                                )}
                            </article>
                        </main>
```

Comment: I had done it previously using socket.io with the rooms feature, you can refer this - https://github.com/sumanth-08/Chat-App

Comment: You can follow this offical documentation to do the above things ==> [Socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/)

Answer (score 0):

since you are sure that message is transferred, I think the issue is the dependency of this `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {           
    //Receive message from back-end
    socket.on('receive_message', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(roomId);
        //If message is for this room
        if (data.room === roomId) {
            console.log(data);
            //Show message
            setMessages((list) => [...list, data]);
        }
    });
}, [roomId]);
```

this dependency means, the code inside this `useEffect` will run on the initial render and after that only when the `roomId` changes. since the roomId will be the same primitive value during chatting, this `useEffect` will not run.

I think you should also pass `socket` object to the first useEffect dependency. This is an object. when you click on send button, `sendMessage` function will run. Since the `messages` state will be updated, the component will rerender which will create a brand new `socket` object. Since `socket` dependency changed, the first useEffect will run and you will be listening for `receive_message` event.